# Workflow for a plugin assignment

Tags: php, mvc, frameworks

I'm starting a new project in PHP, a plugin for a website that grabs additional data from it through cURL, getContents etc and re-tabulates it in excel. It's a local project, basic script like with a very limited UI. Iv'e been using Codeigniter and it's a great framework for websites, and even the Twitter application I'm using it for but I don't think I need MVC (necessarily) for this small project but I also don't want to go bare. What would your typical workflow be for this kind of weekend assignment where your creating a local do-something script or like in my case adding functionality to a website? Is there something in between a light weight MVC framework and a blank page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build MVC-structure, you can do it even without framework. It's easy.
If you want to write little script isn't mandatory to build MVC. Just keep it [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), and it will live long and happy life :)